# Why does modernizer not use var for ret variable

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I was studying the source for the modernizer library and I"m wondering why they don't use the keyword `var` for the variable `ret` in the second line of code? They use it when declaring the variable `version` right above it, but not for `ret`. Can anyone explain why they wouldn't use the keyword `var`?

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They **do** use the `var` keyword. They just use it once and let it apply to all the variables they define at the start of the program (which is a common pattern for JS programming).

```
var version = '2.0.6', // This is a comma, not a semi-colon.
Modernizr = {},
```

… and whoops, while that is the second line of code, it isn't the line you were talking about. The principle is the same there though.

Comment: I feel stupid, didn't catch that. To quick to ask and not actually look at code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ret` is defined with a `var` at the top of the `injectElementWithStyles()` declaration:

```
// Inject element with style element and some CSS rules
injectElementWithStyles = function( rule, callback, nodes, testnames ) {

  var style, ret, node,
      div = document.createElement('div');
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...

  return !!ret;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't analyzed the entire script, but in general you skip the "var" declaration when you want the variable to have a global scope.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: @deceze Did you downvote my comment just because you don't like w3schools?

Comment: No, the downvote and I are [unrelated](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze?tab=reputation).